# How to bring the main form back to the front after the file open dialog is closed

Tags: c#

My C# application starts by opening a form. In the constructor for that form I "showDialog" an openfiledialog. After selecting a file to open, the openfile dialog closes, the file is loaded and the contents displayed in the main form but the main form is buried behind every other open window on my desktop.

I have to find it in the task bar and bring it to focus. I just started the application, I want the form to have focus.

I have written other applications that do not use the openfiledialog and when I start them the main form opens with focus as you would expect.

**How do I make the main form get focus after the openfiledialog closes?**

I have tried

- `this.focus(),`
- `this.activate(),`
- `this.bringtofront();`
- and `this.TopMost = true`;

None of them make any apparent difference at all.

I have research this problem extensively and this are the things everyone suggests and say work, but they don't work for me. Some have insinuated that I am violating all that is holy by trying to make my form topmost. However, I don't think very many people would like to open an application and have the main form for it show up behind everything else.

*Any one have any other ideas about how to make sure my form is "in front", topmost, has focus?*

Comment: The problem is, from which form do you open the file dialog? And a little bit of code will help.

Comment: Have u tried hiding it, then once the File Dialog closes, doing a Show  and Focus?

Comment: "In the constructor for that form i "showDialog" an openfiledialog."  Try calling ShowDialog() from the Load() or Shown() event of the Form instead, and see if that makes a difference...

Comment: Well, I finally figured out how to answer my own question. I ran into a similar problem with another method. Microsoft leaves so much important information out of the documentation.

Comment: this.activate() works but only if executed from the form Load event. I had tried executing it last thing in the constructor, but it has to be in the form.load event.

Comment: I don't know which is the best choice but I can see how moving the showdialog to the load() event would definitely work. I don't know anything about the shown event but it makes sense it would most likely work also, especially since others have mentioned that event as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do it this way, your application will have a brief moment where *no* window is available to receive the focus after the dialog closes.  Windows is forced to find another window to give the focus to, that will be a window of another app.  Your main window eventually appears, now behind that other's app window.

Display the dialog in an event handler of the Shown event instead.  Or use the boilerplate File + Open command.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I believe either the shown or load event makes sense. is there a reason why shown over load? Where does one find information on where to do things? Opening the file in constructor seemed to make sense because this way I was able to load data and initialize everything by the end of the constructor. How is one supposed to know that some things ought to be done in the shown event or load event? Microsoft does not put that information in the documentation.

Comment: where do I find that boilerplate?

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: `this.Activate();` works but if called from the form Load event.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, move the `ShowDialog` out of the constructor, or try putting this in the constructor:

```
this.Shown += OnShown;
```

and move your `ShowDialog` to here:

```
private void OnShown(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var result = new OpenFileDialog().ShowDialog();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the window on top:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ....

    //after your code place the call to the function at the end.       
    SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
}
```

Althought as Mr. hans said and very well you are better off with another design.

Comment: I believe that using user32.dll is mixing an older technology with .net and is not the best way to go. I can't recall exactly what I read but I believe I read something to that affect.