# CommonOpenFileDialog put my window behind all other windows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using CommonOpenFileDialog (from Windows API Code Pack) to pick a directory and somehow it send my window to the back. This is really frustrating as I have to find it in the task bar and click on it again.

Here is the code:

```
    public string ShowPickDirectoryDialog()
    {
        var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog { IsFolderPicker = true };
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            return dialog.FileName;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I found a similiar question here:

[How to bring the main form back to the front after the file open dialog is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20039311/how-to-bring-the-main-form-back-to-the-front-after-the-file-open-dialog-is-close)

But I'm using WPF/MVVM and don't have access to the window object so none of those answer would work. So how do I make sure that my window are at the front after I used CommonOpenFileDialog when I don't have access to the window object? I also can't use the "TopMost" setting as that would put the window in front of the directory picker.

Or is there anything better than CommonOpenFileDialog that I should use (that isn't ugly)?

Comment: You shouldn't be opening dialogs from your view model.  Create an interface that the VM should interact with in order to get filenames. Have the UI inject an implementation that both runs the dialog, but also (because it's in the UI code) brings your form back.  Tada.

Comment: I don't open it inside my view model. My view model receive an interface "FileDialogService" that contains this method. But the problem remains, I don't have access to any view/window so I can move anything to the front/back.

Comment: Why doesn't FileDialogService have access to your window?  It needs it.  It should have it.  Give it, and you're good to go.  Why can't you do that?

Comment: Is `Application.Current.MainWindow.Focus()` an option?

Comment: Will's right, you need to set the dialog's Owner to your MainWindow.

Answer (score 4):

This work well but I prefer to use:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);
var dialogResult = browserDialog.ShowDialog(window);
```

and don't use `window.Focus()`

This make that the window doesn't go to back.

Answer (score 1):

using WPF and MVVM you can try this solution (with MVVMLight nuget installed):

VIEWMODEL

```
    public RelayCommand<YourWindow> ChooseFolderStringCommand { get; set;}
```

In the ctor for example:

```
      ChooseFolderStringCommand = new RelayCommand<YourWindow>( o => ChooseFolder(o));
```

```
    private void ChooseFolder(YourWindow win)
    {
            using (var dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog {IsFolderPicker = true})
            {
                
                CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

                if (result == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
                    ...
            }


            win?.Activate();
        }
```

In the button where trigger ChooseFolder command:

in XAML

```
<Button Command="{Binding ChooseFolderStringCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=YourWindow}">
```

Hope that this help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the currently active window **prior to opening the open file dialog**, and then refocus that after the dialog is closed.

Ideally this method would be in a service. What's nice about this is that nothing else needs to have a reference to the particular owning View -- it can be obtained in this method.

```
    public string PromptForDirectorySelection(string summary, string initialPath)
    {
        var browserDialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog
        {
            Title = summary,
            IsFolderPicker = true,
            InitialDirectory = initialPath,
            AddToMostRecentlyUsedList = true,
            AllowNonFileSystemItems = false,
            EnsureFileExists = false,
            EnsurePathExists = true,
            EnsureReadOnly = false,
            EnsureValidNames = true,
            Multiselect = false,
            ShowPlacesList = true
        };

        // get the current active window, prior to showing and closing this dialog, so it can be re-focused later.
        var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(w => w.IsActive);

        var dialogResult = browserDialog.ShowDialog();
        if (null != window)
        {
            window.Focus();
        }
        if (dialogResult == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
        {
            return browserDialog.FileName;
        }

        return null;
    }
```